How can I access SQL Server PRINT statement output after a temp table create?
Access to PRINT output from within SQL code is normally accessed using the Statement.getWarnings() method. This works well but it seems that all capture of PRINT output stops the first time a script creates a temp table. In this java example:
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = args[0];
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        {
            Statement st1 = connection.createStatement();
            st1.execute("PRINT 'A';\n" +
                    "CREATE TABLE [#x] ([x] INT);\n" +
                    "PRINT 'B';");
            SQLWarning w1 = st1.getWarnings();
            while (w1 != null) {
                System.out.println("temp table statement: " + w1.getMessage());
                w1 = w1.getNextWarning();
            }
        }
        {
            Statement st2 = connection.createStatement();
            st2.execute("PRINT 'A';\n" +
                    "DECLARE @x AS TABLE ([x] INT);\n" +
                    "PRINT 'B';");
            SQLWarning w2 = st2.getWarnings();
            while (w2 != null) {
                System.out.println("table variable statement: " + w2.getMessage());
                w2 = w2.getNextWarning();
            }
        }
    }

the output is
temp table statement: A
table variable statement: A
table variable statement: B

Why doesn't the B get output from the temp table statement?
How can I access what is printed after a temp statement creation?

Out of curiosity, why send PRINT statements from your code to SQL Server, only to read them back again from your code.

he tries to debug his code

You have to properly read the getUpdateCount, getMoreResults etc to access the prints. Some of them are inside resultset objects, which makes fetching even more complicated.

@siggemannen, getUpdateCount returns 0, getMoreResults returns false, there are no result sets.  Under your idea, why would the behaviour be different with a table variable vs a temp table?

siggemannen, playing around with your suggestions I got it to work by calling while (st1.getMoreResults() || st1.getUpdateCount() > -1); before getWarnings. Do you want to put in an actual answer so I can give you credit?
